# RegEx for matching everything except new lines and a special char

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy

I was working on a HW problem that involves removing all of the html tags "<...>" from the text of an html code and then count all of the tokens in that text.

I wrote a solution that works but it all comes down to a single line of code that I didn't actually write and I'm curious to learn more about how this kind of code works.

```
public static int tagStrip(Scanner in) {
     int count = 0; 

     while(in.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = in.nextLine();

         line = line.replaceAll("<[^>\r\n]*>", "");

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);

         while(scan.hasNext()) {
            String word = scan.next();
            count++;
         }
     }
     return count;
}
```

Line 7 is the one I'm curious about.  I understand how the replaceAll() method works.  I'm not sure how that String "<[^>\r\n]*>" works.  I read a little bit about patterns and messed around with it a bit.
I replaced it with "<[^>]+>" and it still works exactly the same.  So I was hoping somebody could explain how these characters work and what they do especially within the construct of this type of program.

Comment: `"<[^>\r\n]*>`  A negative class turns it's items into an _AND_. So, it will stop matching if it finds a  `>` or a  `\r` or a `\n`, basically won't span lines. `<[^>]+>` will span lines since `\r\n` is removed.

Comment: The regex you should be using though is this `<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>` https://regex101.com/r/ZE9Ayg/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### RegEx

If you wish to explore or modify your expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Y43KHL/1/).

`<[^>]+>` may not work since it would pass your new lines, which seems to be undesired.

[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]